# When I press alt in firefox, firefox does not show the menue, but the title

Tags: firefox

I use ubuntu 12.04 64-Bit and the newest firefox (not aurora or beta but the usual).
Sorry for my bad english, i'm german :D

Comment: Tapping `Alt` in 12.04 will bring up the new "HUD" feature (automatically searches menu options).  Holding `Alt` longer will provide the old behavior. Is this what you are seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the menu you can press <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: Fine, Works, THX